# Mui Datepicker with Luxon provider handle the date without DateTime functions

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datepicker, react-hook-form, luxon

I have controlled DatePicker from Mui with integrated Luxon date library used in React Hooks Form. Obviously the app is wrapped in

`<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterLuxon}>`

There is my picker:

```
      <Controller
        name={name}
        control={control}
        render={({ field }) => (
          <DatePicker
            {...field}
            onChange={(e) => {
              resetField(name); // reset given field in React Hooks Form
              console.log(e?.toISOString()); // this function doesn't work
              return field.onChange(e);
            }}
            minDate={new Date()}
            renderInput={(props) => (
              <TextField {...props}/>
            )}
          />
        )}
      />
```

So the object retrieved from DatePicker kinda looks like DateTime of Luxon however it doesn't inherit the DateTime prototype functions like ".toISOString()"

Throwed Error is:
`e.toISOString is not a function`

I did a workaround:

```
interface DateTimeLuxon {
  c: { day : number, hour : number, millisecond : number, minute : number, month : number, second : number } | null,
  invalid:{ reason: string, explanation: string } | null,
  ts: number
}

export const retrieveLuxonDate = (date:DateTime):DateTime => {
  const enteredDate = date as unknown as DateTimeLuxon;
  if (enteredDate.c) {
    return DateTime.fromObject(enteredDate.c);
  }
  throw new Error('Incorrect date');
};
```

So before I want to use DateTime prototype functions, I'm passing the object through but it feels bad.

I also tried to convert it before setting into field like this:

```
      <Controller
        name={name}
        control={control}
        render={({ field }) => (
          <DatePicker
            {...field}
            onChange={(e) => {
              resetField(name); // reset given field in React Hooks Form
              return field.onChange(retrieveLuxonDate(e));
            }}
            minDate={new Date()}
            renderInput={(props) => (
              <TextField {...props}/>
            )}
          />
        )}
      />
```

but after accessing the passed object somewhere else it losses functions again. There is something happening which I don't understand but I would like to. Maybe react-hooks-forms is  cutting down the passed object?